# How to add a block of div contents in between two other divs using javascript only?

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am trying to add a div like below

```
        <div id="topheader" class="topheader">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" title="Library">Library</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" title="My Uni">My Uni</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" title="Staff Intranet">Staff Intranet</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

in between two other divs

```
<div id="w3"> 
.... new div to be here ...
<div id="head">
```

I need to get this done using javascript or motools and not jquery.

Comment: This worked for me using motools.
`var myEl = new Element('div', {id: 'new_div_id'}).inject('w3', 'after');`

Comment: For the sake of completion, without using Mootools, you could also accomplish this with the native `element.insertAdjacentHTML()` which in this case would look like `document.getElementById("w3").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend",newDiv);` (where `newDiv` is a string containing the HTML in your example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `inject`

```
var headEle = document.id('head');

new Element('div', {
    "class": 'topheader',
    "id": 'topheader',
    html: '<ul><li><a href="#" title="Library">Library</a></li><li><a href="#" title="My Uni">My Uni</a></li><li><a href="#" title="Staff Intranet">Staff Intranet</a></li></ul>'
}).inject(headEle, 'before');
```

Here is a working [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxrjhwek/)

Comment: It does copy it in the location I want ; however it still stays in the old location. Is it possible to remove from old location at the same time?

Comment: Actually it does not. My mistake :)

Comment: This particular code snippet creates new div dynamically and injects it. so if already have a div lying somewhere you should probably use that object instead creating new one. then it won't keep an old copy there.

Answer (score 2):

```
var div_before = document.getElementById("w3");
var new_div = document.getElementById("topheader");
div_before.parentNode.insertBefore(new_div, div_before.nextSibling);
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/3bpbcvjp/1/)